# cannot call my javascript function from a button

Tags: javascript

I have a button which I have defined as follows (using semantic UI):

```
<button class="ui left floated submit button" id="csv-button">Copy</button>
<script>
     $("#csv-button").click(getCSV);
</script>
```

Now at the end of my file, before closing the `body` tag, I have:

```
<script>
     function getCSV() {
         alert("Function called")
     }
</script>
```

Now, on click I am getting:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: getCSV is not defined
```

Comment: You're trying to eat the pizza before baking it. JS is executed in the appearance order of the code, all the script tags are not entirely parsed before execution.

Comment: Ah ok, so I should move the function to the top!
But of course the button is only clicked after the page is loaded though...

Comment: Yes, or rather include all your scripts into a single script, which you wrap in `$(document).ready(function () {/* Your code here */});`. The button is clicked after the page was loaded, but the script attaching the event listener is executed when the script tag is met during the page parsing. At that time `getCSV` is not defined , but jQuery needs it to correctly attach the listener.

Comment: Thank you for that explanation. Please do write it as an answer so that I can give you the credit!

Comment: This has probably been asked multiple times, it's just hard to find a good solution because of the nature of the question.

Comment: I put it in a separate file and loaded it. Works fine now. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#csv-button").click(getCSV);
})

function getCSV() {
  alert("Function called")
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="ui left floated submit button" id="csv-button">Copy</button>
```